# Is it possible to get full name from AD instead of svn username in svn log

Tags: apache, svn, active-directory

we are using subversion through Apache web server and check the user credential through active directory. When a user makes a commit it is loged under his username.

We would like to have the full name in the log file to make it easier to locate the person that made the commit. Is this possible with this server setup?